# PHP AJAX redirect after register

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a registration form.  The PHP is checking for errors such as `short password`
AJAX gives an alert with the echo error from PHP.

With PHP, after an if else statement,
the user will be registered and redirected successfully to `index.php` (good)

```php
header('Location:home.php');
exit;
```

The problem is, if there is any error, the user will be redirected to `handler.php` and the echo alert shows there (on white page)

```js
var form = document.querySelector('.register form');
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData(form);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    };
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      if (response.location) {
        window.location.href = response.location;
      } else {
        xhr.send(form_data);
      }
    }
```

---

Example 2: the alerts will display properly at `<div class="msg"></div>` position
(But will also throw the index.php on registration form, where the alerts go)

```js
var form = document.querySelector('.register form');
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = new FormData(form);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = this.responseText;
  };
  xhr.send(form_data);
};
```

So, i want the user to be redirected to `index.php` & also the alerts to be handled by AJAX

Comment: Simple, don't respond with redirects for async requests. Let the client-side handle navigation in those cases

Comment: Also, `if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) { ... }` should be within the `onload` callback

Comment: ... though `xhr.send()` should not be

Comment: Thank you, Phil. Could you please show me the complete solution? I been researching this over 30 hours with no solution, started learning js/ajax so is hard to understand

Comment: I read it, It makes sense but i don't know how to code/implement this.  Simply ``if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299)`` from what i understand is the success response, then ``window.location.href`` to redirect to ``Location:home.php``  (which came from PHP)

Comment: _either a 200 (success) or an error status like 400 (bad request) + error details. The client can navigate to home on success or display error information otherwise_  >> I understand, but how can i implement this with code? Thanks for your time Phil

Answer (score 1):

Regarding responding to AJAX requests with redirects, please see [What is the difference between post api call and form submission with post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230804/what-is-the-difference-between-post-api-call-and-form-submission-with-post-metho). Does a better job explaining than I could.

The basic idea is that when called asynchronously, your PHP should do what it needs to do and respond with either a 200 (success) or an error status like 400 (bad request) + error details.

```php
// make sure nothing is echo'd or otherwise sent to the
// output buffer at this stage

$errors = []; // collect errors in here

// do whatever you need to do with the $_POST / $_FILES data...

// capturing errors example...

if ($_POST['cpassword'] != $_POST['password']) {
    $errors[] = "Passwords do not match!";
}

// use content negotiation to determine response type
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] === "application/json") {
    if (count($errors)) {
        header("Content-type: application/problem+json");
        http_response_code(400);
        exit(json_encode([
            "message" => "Invalid form data or something",
            "errors" => $errors
        ]));
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    exit(json_encode(["location" => "home.php"]));
}

// just a normal request, respond with redirects or HTML
// ...

foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
    <div class="error"><?= $error ?></div>
<?php endforeach;
```

The client can navigate to *home* on success or display error information otherwise

```js
document.querySelector(".register form").addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const form = e.target

  const body = new FormData(form)

  // fetch is much easier to use than XHR
  const res = await fetch(form.action, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json", // let PHP know what type of response we want
    },
    body
  })

  const data = await res.json()

  if (res.ok) {
    location.href = data.location
  } else if (res.status === 400) {
    document.querySelector('.msg').textContent = data.message
    // also do something with data.errors maybe
  }
})
```

Comment: I see what you going for. Im studying the thread + your code, please update the PHP syntax, Thank you Phil.

Comment: @contributor01010 _"please update the PHP syntax"_... sorry, I don't know what that means. _Ed:_ ah, I had a couple of syntax errors. I don't write PHP anymore, can you tell 

Comment: No worries! Im still studying all the basics so this is tremendous help! Appreciate your time to contribute, i'll check again tomorrow and mark as solved when done. Take care! :)

Comment: By the way each 'errors' are handled like this in php,  ``if ($_POST['cpassword'] != $_POST['password']) {
 exit('Passwords do not match!');
}``  

how do i approach, based of the example above?

Comment: I'll add an example but you cannot `echo` anything prior to the content-negotiation

Comment: i tried your solution over the past 4 hours and there are errors or it doesn't work correctly, this is my [handler.php](https://pastebin.com/Q1QSWPjd) (for registration) How would you add your snippet in this?

Comment: sorry im new with both php & ajax so it's hard to deal with. appreciate your time & efforts

Comment: Perhaps you should just use an  entirely different PHP file for async requests if your current one makes it difficult to work with