# When using node, mongoose, and express why do my delete functionality work with a GET method but not a DELETE method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am working on a crud project and I want to delete a item by id using MongoDB, express, and node.

here is the functionality for me to delete an item:

```
router.get('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const topic = await Topic.findById(req.params.id)
        await Topic.remove({ _id: req.params.id })
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error) 
    }    
})
```

here is the ejs portion for when a user click on the item to be deleted:

```
                <div class="modifyTopic">
                    <a href="/edit/<% topic._id %>"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="/delete/<%= topic._id %>"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div>
```

this code actually works but when I change the get method to a delete method like this:

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const topic = await Topic.findById(req.params.id)
        await Topic.remove({ _id: req.params.id })
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error) 
    }    
})
```

it do not work. I get a message in the browser saying "Cannot GET /delete/62def4aae6c2c1914cfa145fer3"
why is this? I should be using the delete method instead of get right? How can I make this work with the delete approach?

Comment: When you click on a link (`<a href ...>`), the browser will send a GET request to the server. If you want to use the DELETE method, you need to write JS code to capture the click event then send your request

Comment: Would I do this by grabbing the element via a querySelector or something and making a fetch to the delete route on my server?

Comment: Yes. You're right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on an `<a>` tag performs a GET request. In order to hit your `router.delete()` route, you have two options...

**Option #1**

Intercept the event with JavaScript and send an async `DELETE` request.

Include a `<script>` section in your view with something like the following...

```js
// Delegated event listener
document.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  const del = e.target.closest("a i.fa-trash");
  
  if (del) { // clicked on a "trash" icon
    e.preventDefault();
    const { href } = del.closest("a"); // get the href
    const res = await fetch(href, {
      method: "DELETE",   // send a DELETE request
      redirect: "manual", // don't follow redirects
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      // request successful
      window.location = res.headers.get("location") ?? "/dashboard";
    } else {
      console.error(res);
    }
  }
});
```

In this scenario, you may not want to respond with a redirect since you're handling the follow-up action client-side. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58230870/283366) for more details

**Option #2**

Use the [method-override](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/method-override.html) middleware to simulate a `DELETE` request.

Register the middleware in your app

```js
const methodOverride = require("method-override");

app.use(methodOverride("_method", {
  methods: ["GET", "POST"], // GET is not recommended, see below
});
```

and add the appropriate query string parameter to your links

```html
<a href="/delete/<%= topic._id %>?_method=DELETE">
  <i class="fas fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
</a>
```

Keep in mind that deleting via GET request can be [very dangerous](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/the_spider_of_doom). I would at the very least recommend using a `<form>` instead

```html
<form action="/delete/<%= topic._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-text">
    <i class="fas fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! So would it be bad practice to make that GET request to do a delete operation?

Comment: @aquilehollins yes, was that not clear in my answer?

Comment: Yeah it is, I missed that part actually. Thank you